# Thumbnails in Nautilus visible only on click

Tags: 14.04, nautilus

On my 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04, Nautilus shows me the thumbnails of .png files only when i select(single click) on the file. Otherwise it is just blank.

A post suggested to remove all the generated thumbnails using :

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.cache/thumbnails/*
```

The behaviour was the same after deleting. I can see that the thumbnails are being generated in `~/.cache/thumbnails/large` whenever i open my png folder in nautilus. So why is Nautilus not showing the thmbnails?

The owner and group of the cache folder is faizal:faizal. The permissions are drwx------.

**Edit :** The behaviour seems inconsistent now after a couple of days(and restarts). The thumbnails mostly show now, but at times it is blank.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Edit->Preferences and select the Preview tab.  Increase the "Only for files smaller than" size to a value larger than the size of your file(s).

Comment: A general-use size is normally 512 MB. This should prevent attempting to show things like `.iso` disk images, etc.

Comment: The value shows 10 MB for me right now. My files are hardly a few kb.

Answer (score 2):

if You uninstalled Totem player then just install it again (even if You are not using it). If You have it already installed, then I would suggest to reinstall it. After that check if thumbnails are working, if not check:

```
/usr/share/thumbnailers/totem.thumbnailer
```

it should contain something like this:

```
[Thumbnailer Entry]
TryExec=/usr/bin/totem-video-thumbnailer
Exec=/usr/bin/totem-video-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o
MimeType=application/mxf;application/ogg;application/ram;application/sdp;applic$
```

if the file is not present or is emty then just paste above code.
I also chowned `/.cache/thumbnails/` to my user like in Kristofers solution & have `libxine1-ffmpeg` in the newest version.
Hope my solution work for You.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that the ~/.cache/thumbnails folder had changed ownership to root for some reason. Fixed with (replacing user with the name of your user):

```
sudo chown -R user:user ~/.cache/thumbnails/
```